# Revising word combination generator

Tags: javascript

I have learned in class how to make a function that generates all combinations of an inputted word. However, how to make it so that instead of a windowed prompt or alert popping up to enter the word and shows all combination on the prompt box, I want to display the result on the screen itself. How would i do that through the code i have already written?

This is my complete code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>Combinations of a Word</title>
<body>
<script>
function combinations(str){
var substr = [];
for (var x = 0; x < str.length; x++) 
{
for (var y = x + 1; y <= str.length; y++) 
{
  substr.push(str.substring(x,y));
}
}
return substr;
}
document.write(combinations(window.prompt("Please enter a word")));
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you please share the html code also ?

Comment: sure ill add it in in a minute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply

```
<input type="text" id="word"/>
<div id="comb"></div>
```

JavaScript

```
function combinations(str) {
    var substr = [];
    for (var x = 0; x < str.length; x++) {
        for (var y = x + 1; y <= str.length; y++) {
            substr.push(str.substring(x, y));
        }
    }
    return substr;
}

var input = document.getElementById('word');
var out = document.getElementById('comb');
input.addEventListener('keyup', function(e){
    out.innerHTML = combinations(this.value).join(',');
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/02huy9g5/)

PS - *your combinations code is wrong*

Comment: thank you so much! this is perfect. and what was it that i had done wrong? the code was working when i executed it on my computer. Please explain.

Comment: It's correct in terms of syntax, but now what I'm wondering is what do you mean by [combinations](http://www.themathpage.com/aprecalc/permutations-combinations-2.htm) :D. If you are getting the desired output, then it's fine.